# Is it possible to create functions similarly to how typeof works, as in using a space instead of parentheses?

Tags: javascript, function

So, you know `typeof`, right?

What I want to do is create a function similar to that, and for this example let's just use a simple `constructorof` thing:

```js
const constructorof = obj => {
    return obj.constructor;
};
```

The syntax for it ends up being like this:

```js
constructorof(someObjectOrWhatever);
```

But I want it to be like this:

```js
constructorof someObjectOrWhatever;
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: no, typeof isn't a function - it is an operator - the obvious question is, why would you want that "syntax" anyway? do `()` scare you :p

Comment: `typeof` isn't a function.  It's an operator, invoked by a keyword.  Adding a keyword to the language would be... non-trivial.  You'd likely need to create your own build of the JavaScript engine, and your own build of any browser in which you intend to use it.  It's a high price to pay to avoid typing two characters and writing standard, supportable code.

Comment: You'll need to create your own language like Microsoft did with typescript. FWIW, a transpiled language is a bit easier to create than a language that compiles to machine code or an interpreter because your "machine" is a very high level language. I've done it myself

Comment: My bad, forgot about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot create new keywords with custom logic in Javascript. You'll either need a function call, with the logic inside the function, or you'll need to inline the logic instead of calling the function. Either way, `constructorof someObjectOrWhatever` won't be valid syntax.